# Get all Module list with status - whether it's enable or disable in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I tried below code which gives me all modules name **not specifying** the status whether it is **enable or disable**.

> __construct

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList $moduleList
) {
$this->moduleList = $moduleList;
}
```

**and here's the list**

```
$modules = $this->moduleList->getAll();
```

**Any idea to get module names with it's status ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a CLI command `bin/magento module:status` which returns the list of enabled modules and disabled. Check `\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleStatusCommand::execute` how it's done.

Basicaly `\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList::getNames` returns you a list of enabled modules and `\Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList::getNames` returns you a full list of all modules, so you will have to do an `array_diff()` to get the disabled modules.

I could not find an option to get the list with statuses out of the box.

Comment: thanks for the answer+1, will try and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can get by using below 2 ways :

---

**EDIT 1 :**

```
protected $fullModuleList;
protected $moduleManager;

public function __construct(
    ...................
    \Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList $fullModuleList,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    ...................
) {

    $this->fullModuleList = $fullModuleList;
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    ...
    $allModules = $this->fullModuleList->getAll();
    $listOfModules = [];
    foreach ($allModules as $key => $value) {
        $listOfModules[] = $key;
    }
    foreach ($listOfModules as $key => $value) {
        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled($value)) {
            echo $value; //Enable Module List
        } else {
            echo $value; //Disable Module List
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

---

**EDIT 2 :**

```
protected $fullModuleList;
protected $moduleList;

public function __construct(
    ...................
    \Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList $fullModuleList,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList $moduleList,
    ...................
) {

    $this->fullModuleList = $fullModuleList;
    $this->moduleList = $moduleList;
}

public function yourFunction()
{
    ...
    $allModules = $this->fullModuleList->getNames(); //List of All Module Names
    $enabled_list = $this->moduleList->getNames(); //List of Enabled Module Names
    $disabled_list = array_diff($enabled_list, $allModules); //List of Disabled Module Names
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer+1 :) achieved, for-each will slow the process :)

Comment: used array diff

Comment: okay. I'l take care. You can take more reference from here : /vendor/magento/magento2-base/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/ModuleStatusCommand.php

Answer (score 2):

You can take help from Magento's core codebase. As you know that below command lists all modules:

```
php bin/magento module:status
```

I found that Magento is using \Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList class to get the list of enabled and disabled modules.

Based on Magento's implementation, I have implemented my code in the following way:

```
<?php
namespace Stack\Base\Block;

class Modules extends \Parent\Class
{
    protected $fullModuleList;

    public function __construct(
        \Other\Dependenciy\Classes,
        \Magento\Framework\Module\FullModuleList $fullModuleList
    ) {

        $this->fullModuleList = $fullModuleList;
    }

    public function modulesList()
    {
        ...
        $allModules = $this->fullModuleList->getAll();
        ...
    }
}
```

I hope it would be helpful.

Comment: It gives the full list of modules not status, still thanks for the answer +1